# Set jQuery Value Using Another Input Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, events, select

I need to update some hidden input fields if the user has changed the value in a dropdown field. There are multiple hidden input fields within multiple forms, but for ease of use there is just one set of dropdowns for the user to filter with.

My question is, I know you can set a value using jQuery like this:

```
$('input[name=hidden_value_name]').val('Sample Value');
```

But I would like to do something like this:

```
$('input[name=hidden_value_name]').val($('#dropdown_field_id').val());
```

The above line isn't working, though. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the `change` event:

```js
$('#dropdown_field_id').on('change', null, function() {
    $('input[name=hidden_value_name]').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="hidden_value_name" /><br>
<select id="dropdown_field_id">
  <option></option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```